# Error when opening Docker Desktop(Windows): "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Post "https://login.docker.com/oauth/token": writing response to login.docker.com:443: connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8888: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Upon opening the app, this message is displayed.